# Javascript split error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write codes for split array values. But I get this error.

```
    var modeOfSending = $('#retrieveValueSupplier').val();    
    var arrayBuild = modeOfSending.split(',');
```

[image: Here more detail]

Comment: Please add your HTML code.

Comment: Before `split` check if `modeOfSending` has any value. Add if condition.

Comment: i'm sorry... i delete my input text id= "retrieveValueSupplier" before :v....Thanks bro

Comment: @JackBashford yes, i forgot my input text id = "retrieveValueSupplier"..thx broo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because modeOfSending is undefined.. have you try debug the value of `$('#retrieveValueSupplier').val();` ?

Comment: yes, i forgot my input text id = "retrieveValueSupplier"..thx broo

Comment: I did nothing..

Answer (score 1):

Before split check if `modeOfSending` has any value and is not `undefined` or `null`.

```js
let val;

val.split(",");
```

```js
let val = "Hello,world";

if(val) {
    console.log(val.split(","));
};
```